# this.map.tick is not a function

Tags: php, chart.js

i am rendering data in a bar chart as a grouped data through php loops.
my data in js is as

```
var graphTarget12 = $("#myBarChartOdometer");

    var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget12, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
                      labels: 'Lahore,Ahmed',
          datasets: [
                          {
              label:'hi',
                data:[320,100]                },
                        {
              label:'hi',
                data:[120,200]                },
                    ]
      }
    });
```

My code in file is as follow

```
<script>
        var graphTarget12 = $("#myBarChartOdometer");

        var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget12, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
            <?php 
              $data = Odometer();
              // echo count($data);
              $name = array();
              for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
                  $arrays = $data[$i];
                  array_push($name,$arrays['groupName']);
                 // print_r(count($meter));
                  // die;
                  $nameImplode = implode(',', $name);
                }
             ?>
              labels: <?php echo "'".$nameImplode."'"; ?>,
              datasets: [
              <?php 
                for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
                  $arrays = $data[$i];
                  $meter = $arrays['odometer'];
                 // print_r(count($meter));
                  // die;
                  $odoValue = array();
              for($s=0;$s<count($meter);$s++)
              { 
                $odo = $meter[$s];
                array_push($odoValue,$odo['odometer']);
              }
              $implode = implode(',', $odoValue);
              ?>
                {
                  label:'hi',
                    data:<?php echo "[".$implode."]";?>
                },
            <?php  } ?>
            ]
          }
        });
    </script>
```

My data format in php is as follow

```
$array = array(
    array('groupName' => 'Lahore','odometer' => array(array('odometer' =>320),array('odometer' => 100))),
    array('groupName' => 'Ahmed','odometer' => array(array('odometer' =>120),array('odometer' => 200)))
);
```

Please help me solve this.i spent 2days already and couldn't figure out solution.
if any other way please show me

Comment: check your browser console for errors. if you are getting errors,just add them in your question.

Comment: Are you sure this is the part where the error appear, i can't see anywhere you use `tick`

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218735/chart-js-t-ticks-map-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label should be like array.

```
 labels: ['Lahore','Ahmed'],
```

You've used like this

```
labels: 'Lahore,Ahmed',
```

Comment: Thanks @Mayank Dudakiya.
Now the data is showing but all the data is formaing in one group istead of its relative group

Comment: let me know if i m doing something wrong because all the errors in console are gone and data is shhowing but no in the correct way..
checked the documentation nothing wrong eith the format don't know what's happening